# Which SKUs of Oracle support WM_CONCAT?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following query:

```
SELECT wm_concat(DISTINCT NAME) as Methods FROM TPM_TRAININGPLAN
JOIN TPM_DELIVERYMETHODS USING (METHODID)
WHERE PROJECTID=735 AND VERSIONID=1
ORDER BY NAME
```

On our production database (some uber expensive Oracle SKU that costs more than my house *), it returns:

```
I/OLT,ILT-WEB,OLT,QRG
```

However, on my local Oracle Express instance (11g) which I use for development, I get the error:

```
>[Error] Script lines: 13-16 ------------------------
 ORA-00904: "WM_CONCAT": invalid identifier
 Script line 13, statement line 1, column 7
```

Does Oracle Express not support this, or is there a work-around (such as can I copy the function from our production server, or run some script to "mimic" it?)  Thanks!

*** No seriously it actually costs more than my house.

**UPDATE:**

As suggested, I tried the LISTAGG function (which is indeed included in both Express 11g and the "Shall we buy an Oracle license or a second yacht" SKU.  This seems to almost work, but has a few drawbacks which I can't find a good workaround for.  First, the query:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(NAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NAME) Methods FROM
TPM_TRAININGPLAN
JOIN TPM_DELIVERYMETHODS USING (METHODID) WHERE PROJECTID=240 AND VERSIONID=1
```

Will return:

```
COMM,COMM,ILT-F2F,ILT-F2F,ILT-F2F,ILT-F2F,ILT-F2F
```

However, I want to remove the dupes.  Changing `NAME` to `DISTINCT NAME` will throw the error `DISTINCT option not allowed for this function`

Well great, we'll just toss a CTE in there:

```
WITH Methods AS
   (SELECT DISTINCT NAME
    FROM TPM_TRAININGPLAN
    JOIN TPM_DELIVERYMETHODS USING (METHODID) WHERE PROJECTID=240 AND VERSIONID=1)
SELECT LISTAGG(NAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NAME) Methods FROM Methods
```

This works, however I forgot to mention that I'm running this entire thing as a nested select in a larger query.  It seems you can have nested selects that include a CTE, however within the query you can no longer refer to the root query, only the CTE.  So now I can't replace 240 and 1 with the appropriate values from the row I'm on.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock-keeping_unit

Comment: @MikeChristensen I am not following this line: "So now I can't replace 240 and 1 with the appropriate values from the row I'm on."  Do you need to group the aggregation on projectId and/or versionId?

Comment: Nope, I'm selecting a bunch of different project/version rows and for each one of those, I want to build a concatenated list using a nested select.  I actually ended up solving this by writing my own version of wm_concat that works on Oracle Express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are in 11GR2, you ought to be able to do [listagg](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm)

```
with fake_data as(

select 'I/OLT' NAME , 1 aa from dual
union all
select 'ILT-WEB' NAME,2 from dual
union all
select 'OLT' NAME,3 from dual
union all
select 'QRG' NAME,4 from dual
)
SELECT 
       LISTAGG(NAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name)  name_list
FROM fake_data
;

NAME_LIST                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
--------------------------
I/OLT, ILT-WEB, OLT, QRG
```

I don't have Oracle Express 11Gr2 to test this (just enterprise). 
But Oracle Express does not have Java support, but you can try to implement it via custom types (once again I don't have Express to test with!)
http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:2196162600402

Comment: Looks almost perfect!  I gave it a try and added my comments above.  I think we're on the right track though.